# Magneto 2 Share a catalog to our privileged customers

Tags: magento2, attributes, products

I need to share magento2 products with some of our valued customers first rather than publishing them online.

They will purchase items if they want but in magento2 how can we generate a special URL for the selected products and how can we show products without enabling them online.

Comment: r u using a enterprise version? if they you can set category permission check user guide else you can use some 3rd party extension to hide category to specific customer group

Comment: No. i am using community edition